# Find the electric field from a distance of a positively charged metal sheet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

> A square metal sheet with area $2\,\mathrm{m^2}$ and thickness $10\,\mathrm{mm}$ has gained a positive charge of $10\,\mathrm{pC}$. Find an the electric field $15$ meters above the metal sheet.

I don't understand how I should tackle this problem. My first intuition was to use Gauss' law, since we have a volume and a enclosed charged. Is that correct? I tried doing that, but ended up with an expression without the variable $d$. I don't know how I would write an expression for the total area of a "rectangle" from a distance $d$ from the metal sheet. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not enough is specified  to answer the question. Is the sheet circular, square, rectangular, or shaped like the silhouette of a giraffe? 15 m  away in which direction?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit that in, thank you for the comment. The sheet is square and the electric field 15 meters above the metal sheet.

Comment: 15 metes above what point on the square?

Comment: You can’t use Gauss’ Law to solve every electrostatics problem. There isn’t enough symmetry here for that law to be useful.

Comment: @G.Smith It is not specified in the question above what point. Why is there not enough symmetry in this question to use Gauss law?

Comment: The field in a plane 15 meters above the sheet various with position in a nontrivial way. You don’t know what any surface integral of the field would be.

Comment: @G.Smith Okey, thank you. Why is the electric field not perpendicular to the surface of the metal sheet, just as in the case of a charged spherical surface? Wouldn't that result in a uniform field?

Comment: The complicated answer is that using integration to calculate the field of a square as the superposition of the field of each infinitesimal charged area element gives a non-perpendicular field. The simpler answer is that there isn’t enough symmetry to make any argument that it should be perpendicular. For an infinite plane there would be, and it is.

Comment: Okey, thank you so much for all the help! So for an infinite plane the E-field is perpendicular? And is the same argument used when one has a cylinder of finite vs infinite length?

Comment: *for an infinite plane the E-field is perpendicular?* Yes.

Comment: *is the same argument used when one has a cylinder of finite vs infinite length?* Yes.